# FluentNhibernate, Nhibernate.Search and Lucene.Net version

Tags: lucene.net, nuget, nhibernate-search

I created a project, and used NuGet to install Nhibernate.Search. During the installation NuGet also downloads the Lucene.Net for me.

With NuGet I have following packages downloaded and installed

- FluentNHibernate.dll: 1.3.0733
- NHibernate.dll: 3.3.1.4000
- NHibernate.Search.dll: 2.0.2.4000
- Lucene.Net.dll: 2.9.4.1

All the dependencies are managed by NuGet. But when I ran following codes

```
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Search.Event;
using NHibernate.Search.Store;

namespace Test {
    public class NHibernateSearchSessionProvider {
        private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
        private static object syncRoot = new object();

        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
            get {
                lock (syncRoot) {
                    if (sessionFactory == null) {
                        sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
                    }

                    return sessionFactory;
                }
            }
        }

        private static ISessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
            var config = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("HomeDB"))
                )
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserAccountMap>())
                .BuildConfiguration();

            // Add NHibernate.Search listeners
            config.SetListener(NHibernate.Event.ListenerType.PostUpdate, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
            config.SetProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "~/LuceneIndex");
            return config.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

An exception message `Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

It looks like this version of NHibernate.Search is still using Lucene.Net 2.9.2.2 not the new one. I can always manually fix all the dependencies, but I prefer to use NuGet.

Anybody has experience how shall I do to make code work?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a configuration error for the [NHibernate.Search nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Search), it states that it supports Lucene.Net 2.9.2.2 *and up*. Try modifying your `packages.config` file to use the 2.9.2.2 version of Lucene (instead 2.9.4.1) and nuget will use the specified version during package restoration.

You will probably need to clean out your bin-folder to remove the "old" 2.9.4.1 assembly.

Answer (score 0):

use Install-Package NHibernate.Search.MB
I tried to fix it but it did not.
Already Nhibernate.Search very old